# cannot access module before initialization in Angular

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to run angular build and it's showing error message which says

cannot access 'VideoModule' before initialization

I have added that module in pages routing with lazy loading

```
{
   path: 'student/courses',
   loadChildren: () => import('./student/video-courses/video-courses.module').then(m => m.VideoCoursesModule),
},
```

and my routing for video-course is as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ListComponent,
    data: { title: 'Courses' }
  },
```

I don't know what went wrong it's working when I try to use using route but it's not working when I try to refresh it.

Issue is only when I use angular build not in local

Comment: Without seeing some more code, cannot predict the issue.

Comment: @ViVi It's causing an issue as I have used lazy loading, I've tried to import the same module in app.component.ts and it worked. What more information you want to have?